# How-to RewriteRule?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following site structure:

```
site.com
\about\
\contact\
\mail\
\ru\
\uk\
\lt\
\ru\o-stranice\
\ru\kontakty\
\ru\pochta\
\uk\storinka\
\uk\zvorotnij-zvyazok\
\uk\skrynka\
\lt\apie\
\lt\kontaktai\
\lt\pastas\
```

and .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Force English
# for http://www.website.com/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?lang=en&article_id=$1

# Other Languages
# for http://www.website.com/ru/
RewriteRule ^(ru|uk|lt)/$ index.php?lang=$1&article_id=index

# Other Languages
# for http://www.website.com/ru/contact/ etc
RewriteRule ^(ru|uk|lt)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?lang=$1&article_id=$2
```

Variable `$article_id` is unique.

```
http://site.com
http://site.com/about/
http://site.net/ru/o-stranice/
```

works fine, but

```
http://site.com/ru/
http://site.com/uk
http://site.com/lt
```

are interpreted as folder name, so

```
echo $_GET ['lang']; //gives en
echo $_GET ['article_id']; //gives "ru".
```

How should I correct the rewrite rules to bring out `ru` page and `index` values? I want the site structure would be easier to you.

Comment: The paths you mentioned at the top... do they physically exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these:

```
# http://site.com
# note: that this rule changes http://site.com to http://site.com/index.php?...
# which matches the next rule, the [L] flag should prevent that
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?lang=en&article_id=index [L]

# http://site.com/anything except ru,uk,lt
# http://site.com/anything except ru,uk,lt/
RewriteRule ^(?!ru|uk|lt)([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=en&article_id=$1

# http://site.com/ru,uk,lt
# http://site.com/ru,uk,lt/
RewriteRule ^(ru|uk|lt)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&article_id=index

# http://site.com/ru,uk,lt/anything
# http://site.com/ru,uk,lt/anything/
RewriteRule ^(ru|uk|lt)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&article_id=$2
```

Ideally you should decide whether you allow URLs ending with `/` or not. Then, say you choose to *have* a trailing `/`, 301-redirect all no-slash requests to have-shash URLs. I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reorganize your rules. When you type in `http://site.com/ru/`, Apache sees the path as `ru/` which *does* match your first rule (zero or more characters which are not a forward slash, followed by a forward slash; *check*).

The general rule of thumb when organizing your rewrite rules is to list the **deepest / most detailed levels first**. Since they are the most detailed, you'll have fewer problems. Having less detailed rules before more detailed rules increases the risk of a rule up the chain triggering before the rule you actually want to trigger.

Try simple reversing them all in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Other Languages
# for http://www.website.com/ru/contact/ etc
RewriteRule ^(ru|uk|lt)/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1&article_id=$2

# Other Languages
# for http://www.website.com/ru/
RewriteRule ^(ru|uk|lt)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&article_id=index

# Force English
# for http://www.website.com/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?lang=en&article_id=$1
```

Comment: You were faster than me :) +1.

Comment: when i type hxxp://site.com/ru/ (ru - russian, uk - ukrainian, lt - lithuanian) $_GET[] writes: "en" and "index.php", i need that $_GET writes "ru" and "index.php" (as main value for identical translated language content in russian)

Comment: http://www.website.com/ru/contact/ writes ru and contact(correctly); http://www.website.com/contact/ writes en and contact(correctly); http://www.website.com/ru/ writes en and index.php(not correctly); http://www.website.com/ nothing writes(correctly).

Comment: @vp1: I assume the problem you're having is that you are not including the trailing `/` in your URL, which is specifically included in your rewrite rules. Try adding a `?` at the end, see my updated answer.

Comment: @animuson: if i including "/" it always writes: en and index.php (mayby in configuration issues). in previous comment i write queries with slashes! i want that "/ru/" display russian language content(such as website.com/ but translated in russian) can i contact you?